# C++ Own Observer Pattern

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers, observer-pattern, observers

I'm designing an observer pattern which should work this way: observer calls `AddEventListener` method of `EventDispatcher` and passes a string which is the name of the `event`, *PointerToItself* and a *PointerToItsMemberMethod*

After that `event` happens inside of the `EventDispatcher`; it looks through the list of subscriptions and if there are some, assigned to this event calls the `action` method of the `observer`.

I've come to this `EventDispatcher.h`. **CAUTION** contains bit of pseudo-code.

The are two questions:

1. How do I define the type of `action` in `struct Subscription`?
2. Am I moving the right way?

**PS**: No, I'm not gonna use `boost` or **any** other libraries .

```
#pragma once

#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct Subscription
{
        void*                   observer;
        string                  event;
        /*  u_u  */             action;
};

class EventDispatcher
{
    private:
        vector<Subscription>    subscriptions;

    protected:
        void                    DispatchEvent ( string event );

    public:
        void                    AddEventListener ( Observer* observer , string event , /*  u_u  */ action );
        void                    RemoveEventListener ( Observer* observer , string event , /*  u_u  */ action );
};
```

This header implements like this in `EventDispatcher.cpp`

```
#include "EventDispatcher.h"

void    EventDispatcher::DispatchEvent ( string event )
{
    int key = 0;
    while ( key < this->subscriptions.size() )
    {
        Subscription subscription = this->subscriptions[key];
        if ( subscription.event == event )
        {
            subscription.observer->subscription.action;
        };
    };
};

void    EventDispatcher::AddEventListener ( Observer* observer , string event , /* */ action )
{
    Subscription subscription = { observer , event , action );
    this->subscriptions.push_back ( subscription );
};

void    EventDispatcher::RemoveEventListener ( Observer* observer , string event , /* */ action )
{
    int key = 0;
    while ( key < this->subscriptions.size() )
    {
        Subscription subscription = this->subscriptions[key];
        if ( subscription.observer == observer && subscription.event == event && subscription.action == action )
        {
            this->subscriptions.erase ( this->subscriptions.begin() + key );
        };
    };
};
```

Comment: To bad you're not using boost, since that would allow an easy & type safe solution which would outperform your current approach and be more flexible. Is C++11 solutions allowed?

Comment: I don't really know yet, what C++11 is... It's a new standard, right? I wonder, if my `g++` knows it already? New standard is ok to use, it's not a library...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you should just create a class to be derived by "users":

```
class Action {
   public:
      friend class EventDispatcher;

      virtual SomeResultType DoThis() = 0;

   private:
      /* Some common data */
};
```

Just pass some derived-from-class-Action typed variable to AddEventListener. When the corresponding event is triggered, just fill in the common data and call the DoThis() method.

```
void EventDispatcher::DispatchEvent ( string event )
{
    int key = 0;
    while ( key < this->subscriptions.size() )
    {
        Subscription subscription = this->subscriptions[key];
        if ( subscription.event == event )
        {
            subscription->action();
        };
    };
};
```

For AddEventListener:

```
void EventDispatcher::AddEventListener ( Observer* observer , string event , Action* action )
{
    Subscription subscription = { observer , event , action );
    this->subscriptions.push_back ( subscription );
};
```

An example of a Action derived class:

```
class myAction: public Action {
   public:
      // Implement the DoThis() method
      void SomeResultType DoThis() {
          cout << "Hello World!";
          return SomeValue;
      }
};

// To use the action,
myAction* act = new myAction;
myEventDispatcher.AddEventListener(someObserver, "HelloWorld", act);
```

This is one of the safest way to implement actions (and callbacks).

Comment: Can I just pass to `AddEventListener` a pointer to a member function of the `observer` and call it from the `EventDispatcher`? How can I do it? Thank you?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Please avoid using function pointers. In your DispatchEvent() method, you could just have action->DoThis();

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't get it... Let's say, observer has a non-static method `DoSmth()`. How do I pass this method to the `EventDispatcher` and how will `EventDispatcher` call this method later?

Answer (score 3):

You could either define an Action class or pass a lambda function (C++11). In the latter case, action could be defined as

```
function<void (EventDispatcher*)> action;
```

and you would register the observer as follows

```
Observer * me = this;
observable->AddEventListener (this, "EventName", [me] (EventDispatcher* dispatcher) {
   // code here; me is available
});
```

You should probably use smart weak pointers to store the Observers in the EventDispatcher, such that you do not have to care for un-registering.

Edit: Added following example (just one subscription possible, but should illustrate the idea -- you have to be careful that you do not reference an object that does no longer exist)

```
struct Observable {
   std::weak_ptr<function<void (const Observable&)>> action;

   void AddEventListener (std::weak_ptr<function<void (const Observable&)>> theAction) {
      action = theAction;
   }

   void EventRaised () {
      if (!action.expired ()) {
         auto theAction = action.lock ();
         (*theAction) (*this);
      }
   }
};

struct Observer {
...
   void CallOnEvent (const Observable & observable) {
      // do something
   }

   // field to store the action as long as it is needed
   std::shared_ptr<function<void (const Observable&)>> action;

   void ... {
      auto me = this;
      action = std::make_shared<function<void (const Observable&)>> (
         [me] (const Observable& observable) {
             me->CallOnEvent (observable);
         }
      );
      // we could have as well used std::bind
      observable.AddEventListener (action);
   }
};
```

Comment: Can I just pass to `AddEventListener` a pointer to a member function of the observer and call it from the `EventDispatcher`? How can I do it? Thank you?

Comment: @Kolyunya just pass `std::bind(Observer::whateverMethod, me)` as function instead of the lambda.

Comment: I just dont't get your code... It must be new standard c++11, I don't know it yet... Thanks and sorry...

Answer (score 1):

In its simplest form u_u could be a function pointer e.g.

```
typedef void (*u_u)(void*); // or whatever arguments u like
```

then you just supply a function that is called whenever the event is triggered.

```
void myaction(void* arg)
{
  ...
}

Subscription s;
...
s.action = myaction;
```